# How do I add a limit to the number of guesses in a number guessing game?

Tags: java

I cannot figure out how to add a limit to the number of guesses in my number guessing game.  I have tried adding a for statement after the while statement but that made the code just stop at the tenth guess and there was no winner ever.  I deleted the while statement and just did the for statement which ensured that the user got the correct answer every ninth guess.  My code is divided into two classes as requested by my professor.  I am including both below.  I would appreciate all the help I can get.  Thank you!

GuessingGame.java: Main Class

```java
public class GuessingGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Guess().doGuess();
    }
}
```

Guess.java

```
class Guess {
    private int answer = 0;
    int tries = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int guess, i;
    boolean win = false;
    int amount = 10;
    
    public Guess() {
        answer = generateRandomNumber();
    }

    //Generate a private number between 1 and a thousand
    private int generateRandomNumber() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        return rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
    }

    public void doGuess() {
        while(!win) {
            System.out.println("You are limited to ten attempts."
                    + "Guess a number between 1 and 1000: ");
            guess = input.nextInt();
            if (guess > 1000 ) {
                System.out.println("Your guess is out of the range!");
            } else if (guess < 1) {
                System.out.println("Your guess is out of the range!");
            } else if (guess == answer) {
                win = true;
                tries++;
            } else if (guess < answer && i != amount -1) {
                System.out.println("Your guess is too low!");
                tries++;
            } else if (guess > answer && i != amount -1) {
                System.out.println("Your guess is too high!");
                tries++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Congragulations! You guessed the number!"
                + "The number was: " +answer);
        System.out.println("It took you " + tries + " tries");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an if-statement inside the while loop.

```
 public void doGuess() {
           while(!win) {
            System.out.println("You are limited to ten attempts."
                    + "Guess a number between 1 and 1000: ");
            guess = input.nextInt();
            if(tries > 9) {
              ...whatever you want to happen when user has reached 10 guesses...
            }
```